# Typescript: trying to replace ternary operator with functional implementation

Tags: typescript

I am trying to replace a ternary operator with functional implementation. Finding it hard to write the typescript type for the below code where `any` is written.

1. How can I pass a generic type to `thn` or `els` function param which can accept a `function` or `any other type` , so that the type checking is strict and `returns` the correct type?
2. How can I remove `any` type in the below code with correct types?

```
interface Predicate {
    (...args: any): boolean;
}

const ifThenElse = (bool: boolean | Predicate) => (thn: any) => (els: any) : any => {
 if(bool) {
   if(typeof thn === 'function') {
     return thn()
   }
   return thn
 }
  if(typeof els === 'function') {
     return els()
   }
   return thn
}

var coffeesToday = ifThenElse(true)(3)(1);
var coffeesTomorrow = ifThenElse(false)(() => 3)( () => 4);
console.log('coffeesToday', coffeesToday)
console.log('coffeesTomorrow', coffeesTomorrow)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=48&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQgE2AulkDeAsAFDLnIAUAdLXFAOYDOAXMnCAJ4CUbARgHsBAGwgcA3KQC+pAPQAqecgASAgO7JcIZAElkABzhMm7ZAwghoOZGE76UYAcgAGYABYhnyAVBcRhTF4wAK4gCGDAAtqGUHAAtshqbjhumhzsCEj6YKbOIWERUV4+Lhyc3u7QNnYQXvKypAhRTDnAMAAqbhYAogEoALxUgiL8QqLpAD5oGNi4kNzI-QB8VO4gbGULy1T+rOxcWyvEZG2Uw8ILxxSntvYCMDYei-2DAOT54ZEgr5ekFOQYMDBKDaNaUbh-cgyMgAiBAkGPEB-aHkG41e7IXbPN4fQrfX4wiiA4HaXbgyHIFGw+GgjzSUikABu9E09xgEAgTHaAkwcHKgzanR6fUoYCgwQg3EoAGYpQBGbiSEjM3xNGDszncuI+KDqRbIQVdEC9JgQSjwPpS8GLFayyhUQ7IAAsisazREEGowgEDEorzVGq5PL5rwANKz1Ryg7yeG6QEwPV6fX6A1GtTr1GGI4H01BdWpuEA)

Comment: `function or any other type` is in fact `any` type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you could do:

```
type Result<T> = T extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : T

const ifThenElse = (bool: boolean | Predicate) => <T>(thn: T) => <E>(els: E): Result<T> | Result<E> => {
  if (bool) {
    if (typeof thn === 'function') {
      return thn()
    }
    return thn as Result<T> | Result<E>
  }
  if (typeof els === 'function') {
    return els()
  }
  return els as Result<T> | Result<E>
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQgE2AulkDeAsAFDLIAUAdDXFAOYDOAXMnCAJ4CUrARgPb8ANhHYBuUgF9SpMBwAOKAEoRGAVyFgAPABUAfMgC8yHcggAPSCEyNKNKnSat2HANoBdLkYOgY0ZErIAPwByKw6MiQI-CCMYMjAMDoAFhAgAKJCjCjGFALCfIIi7MgAPmgY2LiQXoYGunoUYMkg4bX16Y0QWazpPAGqGtr6ZQPqmlqd3oSk5ImU+UJexGTkCTCUcor8G80gRobGAOQwaiAIYMAxR8uza+QYYGpQ+3sUXHfk0qsPEE8vyD2bFsKnGwwM5VBQ0meju3zmGyaCggOzMWQOx1O50u11uP2Qj2e+26jHecLuhIBJOBY2hI0hgwmnSkkQAbnRkNEYH5VDp+Jg4BwjOsUmlMtkmlA1BAuBQAMyygCMXAkJHZUE5Ox5jD5AFt+FAoPwAO7CxKijJZCAUeBW2XvaYKigOurIAAsKtI0ViwggVCE-HoFCOXO1fIFHCOABpNdyILz+YKPlEYoxff7A8HQ-Gdfx9YaTdHY2G8wajcauEA)

So the resulting return type is union of both possible branches.

Comment: Thank you, understood `infer` type usage in a better way.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the `typecasting` in the solution provided?

Comment: I didn't find a way.. Slightly shorter one: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQgE2AulkDeAsAFDLIAUAdDXFAOYDOAXMnCAJ4CUrARgPb8ANhHYBuUgF9SpMBwAOKAEoRGAVyFgAPABUAfMgC8yHcggAPSCEyNKNKnSat2HANoBdLkYOgY0ZErIAPwByKw6MiQI-CCMYMjAMDoAFhAgAKJCjCjGFALCfIIi7MgAPmgY2LiQXoYGunoUYMkg4bX16Y0QWazpPAGqGtr6ZQPqmlqd3oSk5NGx8SAW8cb5QsHIzSBhZlkSZMgYYGpQ23KK-DDIS5ZGhsYA5DBqIAhgwDEPGxQ38XC2ADEXm8PiAuBQvKxfvtpCRSAA3OjIaIwPyqHT8TBwDhGBJJVIZLIQJpQNQQcEAZnBAEYuPtEVBkZc0YwMQBbfhQKD8ADuuMSKTSmWyFHgRPBEOmVIokrqyAALHTSPNGMIIFQhPx6BQHiiWRisRwHgAaJmoiDozHYrjKmKqkQarU6vUW1n8Dlc3kms3692c7k8rhAA